# Can't display data from the ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table in my database and I want to get the name field without repetition.
But I get this error:

'string' does not contain definition for 'ID'.
When I debug my code, I find the variables full with data, until the foreach the error shows up.

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
            HREntities db = new HREntities();
            var areas = db.Area.Select(area => area.Area + area.ID).Distinct().ToList();
            if(areas != null)
                ViewBag.areas = areas;

            return View();
}
```

The view's code:

```
 @foreach (var area in ViewBag.areas)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <input name="group4" type="radio" id="@area.ID" class="radio-col-blue-grey" />
        <label for="@area.ID">@area.Area</label>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Side note - its hard it imagine the combining the `ID` and `Area` properties would result in duplicates so you `.Distinct()` does not seem necessary. And I would really strongly recommend you pass the model to the view rather than using `ViewBag` and strongly type your model to the view, including using the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your html.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, that what I just did. Thank you for your explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Create` method in the controller, you are creating a `List<string>`on following line:

```
var areas = db.Area.Select(area => area.Area + area.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```

You then pass this list to the ViewBag, but as it is now a list of strings and not a `List<Area>`, it won't have an ID property there.

While debugging, check the type of the variable `areas`, you'll see. Your markup code in the foreach loop should look like this:

```
<input name="group4" type="radio" id="@area" class="radio-col-blue-grey" />
<label for="@area">@area</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.Select()` query is returning `IEnumerable<string>`, not a collection of `Area` objects (and a `string` does not have a property named `Id`)

Based on your query your view code should be just

```
@foreach (var area in ViewBag.areas)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <input name="group4" type="radio" id="@area" class="radio-col-blue-grey" />
        <label for="@area">@area</label>
    </div>
}
```

Alternativey you need to return  a collection of your model